# Is it possible to `inline` a `method`?

Tags: performance, methods, common-lisp, inline

I've done some cursory reading on [inlining declamations](http://john.freml.in/sbcl-optimise-builtins) and read up on the [relevant](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_inline.htm) CLHS [pages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_declar.htm), but can't easily see an explicit answer.

Is it reasonable to `(declaim (inline foo))` when `foo` is declared using `defmethod` rather than `defun` (the latter of which is explicitly a covered case)? How about if `foo` is the `reader` function of a `class`? Is the effect of this inlining noticeable in performance terms? Is it implementation-specific in some way?

For simple methods under tight constraints, it might be reasonable to re-write as a `defun` for performance specifically, but that's sometimes difficult or impossible. Are there general optimization strategies that one can bring to bear on Common Lisp methods without re-writing them as functions?

Comment: See https://github.com/guicho271828/inlined-generic-function

Comment: @coredump - According to that, it looks like the situation is "inlining generic functions/methods normally results in negligible performance gains, and can be improved in the optimized case at the cost of using an external library, an extra meta-class declaration, and poorer performance in the non-optimized case". It is available from `quicklisp` as `inlined-generic-function`, so it'd be economical to explore. Do you know if it also hits the `reader`/`accessor` case? And also, wanna post that as an answer?

Comment: Note that Common Lisp programs don't call individual methods, but generic functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inlining methods makes little sense because the way a CL compiler can do it when it can be sure in advance about what function is being called. When there is an explicit call to `(foo x)` with `foo` being inlined, the definition of `foo` can be substituted. However, when the code being compiled is `(funcall method x y)`, there is no way you can inline the function if `method` is unknown.

And this is what generic functions do. In fact, you don't call methods yourself, you let the object system determines which methods should be called. CLOS allows you to add and remove methods, so you have to live with the fact that the system is dynamic and have some runtime cost (some implementations can seal generic functions, apparently, to prevent further changes). However, it is quite useful in practice and saves a lot of development time. I have yet to find a case where dynamic dispatch is costing too much, but I don't have experience with very large sets of methods.

You can have a look at Robert Strandh's paper [Fast generic dispatch for Common Lisp](http://metamodular.com/generic-dispatch.pdf) for ideas about making generic dispatch faster. 
There is also a library providing [Inlined Generic Functions](https://github.com/guicho271828/inlined-generic-function), where apparently generic functions can be efficiently dispatched at compile-time under appropriate circumstances.